# How do I get values out of my file in Java and calculate them?

Tags: java, string, file, csv, io

Okay, so I have this piece of code to take my .csv file which has these values in it.

```
Alice Jones,80,90,100,95,75,85,90,100,90,92
Bob Manfred,98,89,87,89,9,98,7,89,98,78
```

I want to take the names and then the corresponding grades and calculate an average for them. The part that I am stuck on is actually retrieving these values in the file so I can actually use them. What would I use to read the string so I can pull the integers out?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
try{
// Open the file that is the first 
// command line parameter
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("filescores.csv");


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
// Print the content on the console
System.out.println (strLine);
}
//Close the input stream
in.close();
}catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());

}
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text. It is redundant and confusing. Please remove it from your example as this bad code gets copied a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet that should help you to start.

```
String[] parts = strLine.split(",");
String name = parts[0];
int[] numbers = new int[parts.length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `String#split` to read the values of one line into an array:

```
String[] values = strLine(",");

// debug
for (String value:values) {
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

The value at index 0 is the name, the other array fields contain the numbers as strings and you could use `Integer#parseInt` to convert them into integer values.